# Magento : How to Reaggregate Reviews

Tags: magento-1.9, product, customer, import, review

I am trying to import reviews to our Magento 1.9V, so after finishing I noticed that stars aren't showing on product. I used this [module](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-review-import-export.html) to import reviews, also I edit extension to import stars in my custom rating option. And after I dig deep I found that:

1- In the Admin area:

Summary Rating  isn't Available

[image]

2- In the database product is exist in `review` table.

3-In the database product is not exist in `rating_option_vote_aggregated` table.

So how we can re-aggregated value of imported review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix this matter a while a go, and here is what I did in /Model/Convert/Adapter/Reviewimport.php:

```
public function saveRow(array $data)
{
    $product_id = $data['entity_id'];
    if ($product_id) {
        if ($data['customer_id'] == '') {
            $customerid = NULL;
        }
        else {
            $customerid = $data['customer_id'];
        }
        $_review = Mage::getModel('review/review')
            ->setCreatedAt($data['created_at'])
            ->setEntityPkValue($product_id)
            ->setEntityId(1)
            ->setStatusId($data['status_id'])
            ->setTitle($data['title'])
            ->setDetail($data['detail'])
            ->setStoreId($data['store_id'])
            ->setStores($data['store_id'])
            ->setCustomerId($customerid)
            ->setNickname($data['nickname'])
            ->save();
        if ($data['option_id']) {
            Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
                ->setRatingId($data['option_id'])
                ->setReviewId($_review->getId())
                ->setCustomerId($customerid)
                ->addOptionVote($data['review_score'], $product_id);
        }
        $_review->aggregate();
    }
}
```